# Get CSS properties in a directive for children elements

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, dom

I'm currently looping through the child elements of the element that the directive is attached to, and adding callbacks for mouseup and mousedown:

```
    var dragDroppables = element[0].children;

    for (var elementIdx = 0; elementIdx < dragDroppables.length; elementIdx++) {
        var bindElement = dragDroppables[elementIdx];

        var elementID = bindElement.attributes['id'].value;

        if(elementID == "DragDroppable") {

            var bindElementAngular = angular.element(bindElement);

            bindElementAngular.on('mousedown', function() {
                bindElementAngular.css('background-color', 'rgb(17, 83, 252)');            
                elementHeldDown = bindElementAngular;
                isElementHeldDown = true;

                //window and angular.window are both undefined in this case
                var style = angular.window.getComputedStyle(bindElementAngular);         
                heldDownElementWidth = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('width'));
                heldDownElementHeight = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('height'));     
            });
            bindElementAngular.on('mouseup', function () {
                bindElementAngular.css('background-color', 'rgb(73, 122, 255)');
                isElementHeldDown = false;
            });
          }
       }
    }
```

Now it complains that the window object is undefined. When I had this functionality in a controller getting the window object directly (without calling it from the angular object) worked fine. Now that it's in the directive it seems to not work anymore. How can I get CSS properties from an arbitrary DOM object inside of a directive?

Comment: there is a way, might be some sort of hack.
Access root object with parents() function of any element that is accessible in this scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try to inject the window object in the directive

```
directives.insertStyle = [ "$window", function($window){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var elementStyleMap = $window.getComputedStyle(element[0], null);

        }
    }   
}];
```

Comment: Apologies but I'm new to Angular. Is this another directive attached to the same DOM object or separate directive defined before my directive? How would I call this?